# How to change the payload of a packet on retransmission?

Tags: scapy

I want to try to implement the RSTEG method using scapy. That is, send a packet, the receiver does not send a confirmation message, this packet is sent again, but with a steganogram in the payload, the receiver again does not send a confirmation message. Then this package is sent again, but without the steganogram. (the same packet is sent three times, but a steganogram is sent a second time.) Is it possible to implement it with Scapy, How can I do that?

With the creation of packets and  they are sent there is no problem. I can use timeout and retry to not receive the confirmation message and resend the package. But I do not understand how in this case to change the payload and at the end to get a confirmation message.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like -

```py
packet=IP() / UDP() / ... / Raw(load=your_data) # the ... are for all your other protocols
response=sr1(packet, timeout=5)
if response is None:
    # response is not received, send it 2nd time
    packet[Raw].load = your_data_with_steganogram
    response=sr1(packet, timeout=1)
    if response is None:
        # response is not received, send it 3rd time
        packet[Raw].load = your_data
        response=sr1(packet, timeout=1)
```